# Wordpress Plugin Doubts

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

First of all, sorry for my mistakes, i’m not an english native.
I’m developing a new wordpress plugin, but i’m new and i have doubts. I have basic knowledges of php.

The plugin’s mission is to create a few “landing pages” and add the required registries to de database to make it work properly. It works with OptimizePress.
At the moment, we created an admin menu with a button, and if you press it, the button insert all the registries necessary to work (pages, postmeta, plugin related info…)
But i have the next questions:

1- now we have a few global parameters in the wp-config file, and we use it like “switches” to modify the “performance” (functioning) of the page. the problem is, that we know that the “globals” mustn’t stay at wp-config file, then, we think about save that info in the database, but we don’t know how to do to charge that info in all the wordpress or non wordpress pages (like wp-config does).

2 - In our plugin we have a file called “includes.php”, we can require that file from any other page of the plugin to load the “core files” of wordpress. The question is : what is the better way to do this? to load all necessary wordpress files to use the functions like site_url, get_permalink…
The code from includes.php is:

```
 <?php

//that switch change the root path if we are working on localhost or not
switch ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']) {
    case 'localhost':
        if (strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], ‘web1’) !== false ){
            $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/web1/httpdocs';
        }
        if (strpos($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'], ‘web2’) !== false ){
            $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/web2/httpdocs';
        }
    break;
    default:
        $location = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}

require_once ($location . '/wp-config.php');
require_once ($location . '/wp-load.php');
require_once ($location . '/wp-includes/pluggable.php');
require_once ($location . '/wp-includes/rewrite.php');

global $wpdb;

if( !isset($wpdb) )
{
require_once ($location . '/wp-config.php');
require_once ($location . '/wp-includes/wp-db.php');
}

$name = get_bloginfo( name );


// Global L1 is declared on wp-config

$post_id = L1;
$post = get_post($post_id);
$slug = $post->post_name;
$enlace = get_site_url();
$landing1=$enlace."/". $slug ."/";


include ('languages/lang.php');
?>
```

Thanks a lot, if you have a doubt cause of my grammar ask it, don’t worry,

Regards!

Comment: Look at the syntax highlight here on the site, it shows that you have syntax errors on youtr code... Pay attention to the quotes you're using, `'` is different from `‘`. A decent [tag:ide] will show those errors.

Comment: The syntax is ok in my local file, i changed a bit the code before showing it

Comment: The doubts are not because of your english, which is fine, it's not clear *at all* what's your problem and what's your goal. For starters, if you're including core files in a plugin, much probably you're doing it wrong.

Comment: 1- Now we use constants in wp-config as plugin config, but this is wrong, i want to save all the config in the database, but I don't know how to do to load that configuration in all wordpress pages when de plugin is active. Like the wp-config does.

Comment: Which constant are those? And why do you need  load them in *all pages*?

Comment: 2- The file that i show is includes.php, is a file that we use as "core" of our plugin, with this file, we can use wordpress functions like site_url, get_post_thumbnail etc... But I saw other plugins and they doesn't have a file "including" the wordpress core files. There is another way to do this? Sorry if is difficult to understand, but my vocabulary is limited, is hard for me to explain the problem in detail.

Thank you a lot for you effort!

Comment: Yes, i need to load them in all pages, because i will change some things in the wordpress theme (is a custom theme) and plugin files.

Comment: Check [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Options_API) and [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=get_option%20is%3aanswer)